# Loading local images into uiwebview

Tags: javascript, iphone, uiwebview

The only problem i have is, that i want to reload some images in the WebView.
Therefore, i added a simple Javascript Method, doing this:

```
function replaceImage(id, src) { 
     document.getElementById('img'+id).src=src;
}
```

call it via

```
[webView stringByBlehBleyJAvascript:@"replaceImage(....);"];
```

and voila *rataplan* ...  *drum roll*    - i can see the new image - right after the image disappears completaly for about 1 second.
Now i wonder - the image i load is about 30KByte in size. not too much, at least not to much it should take 60 seconds.
I also tried the JS-Image-Object to loadit, and set the dom-image-str attribute to the loadded one. same results :/
The complete amount of dom-elements are about .. 12-15. so the getElementById is not the bottle neck.
Any idea how to load a static file w/o delay?
Btw: just tested it in simulator, since my mobile is broken..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this at the bottom of your HTML:

```
<div style="display: none"><img src='img.png'/></div>
```

I had a similar problem with a very small, locally stored image, when displayed via JavaScript would take 2-3 seconds to display. i.e.

```
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "<img src='img.png'/>";
```

However, if the image is included in your HTML, it apparently gets cached. Then when you display it with JS, it shows up immediately.

Comment: solved it similar to this, just found this old question and your matching answer ;) thanks Peter

Answer (score 0):

Why not just call the web view's `reload` method?

Or just tell the webView to load the content again in the same way you did the first time around. It could be that the delay is just because you're asking the web view to run some javascript, which probably involves a bunch of extraneous stuff.

Comment: Hey Charlie,  i got 3 Images, each one representing a status. i only want to change 1 status. now, this cannot be done via css because a status-change is made by loading a photo (live image) from foreign server.